# websocket-rails no connections in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I am using websocket-rails gem for websocket connection to my rails app - the thing is it works perfectly on my computer - but on my production machine it just won't work.

when I connect - it writes to websocket_rails log - that I am connected - however when I try to send data to the connection - it does nothing.

I added some logs to help me find the issue, and it seems `WebsocketRails.users` is empty - meaning there are no connections - even though there are.

however, when I really disconnect from the websocket connection, it logs the disconnection - and seeing the code, it checks if it's connected before logging the disconnection - so i finds it connected.

this is the code that triggers an event on the connection

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user
  has_many :students

  after_update  :notify_location_changed, if: Proc.new { |route| route.loc_latitude_changed? || route.loc_longitude_changed? }

  def notify_location_changed
    logger.info "#{self.id} location_updated"
    logger.info "connections: #{WebsocketRails.users.users}" #this is empty - even when there is a connection open - it still pings.
    channel = WebsocketRails[self.id.to_s]
    WebsocketRails.logger.info "sending to the following subscribers of channel #{self.id} - #{channel.subscribers}"
    channel.subscribers.each do |connection|
      logger.info "sending to the following connection #{connection}"
      options = {}
      logger.info "#{connection.data_store}"
      user = connection.data_store[:user].actable
      logger.info "user: #{user.to_json}"
      data = [loc_latitude: loc_latitude - user.pick_up_lat, loc_longitude: loc_longitude - user.pick_up_long].to_json
      options.merge! :channel => channel.name, :token => channel.token
      options[:data] = data
      event = WebsocketRails::Event.new :location_updated, options
      connection.trigger event
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31510380/edit), `websocket-rails` isn't an active project and it's last commit was a long time ago.

I would recommend using alternatives such as [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) or [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi).

Connecting a Plezi app with Rails is explored in the Plezi's read file and seems quite easy to accomplish.