# Rails - RealTime Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I am creating appliction which recives HTTP POST request, saves it to hash and moves to Redis and it works fine so far. Now I would like to push these datas to client IN REAL TIME. I though about using WebSocket and after generating WebSocket (rails g websocket_rails:install) meet with the first issue. I cant to post requestes anymore.

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
localhost:3000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
```

- What should I do then?
- Using WebSocket is proper way?
- Can I first receive POST request and then create a channel to pushing datas to client?

Comment: Provide your source code, related to web socket.

Comment: I change nothing so far. It generated me three files: create  config/events.rb
      create  config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb
      append  app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: Ok, where exactly do you see that error you are seeing? Rails log? Console?

Comment: console but now I get other issue:
RuntimeError (eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server):

Comment: I think you need to use the `thin` server in order to leverage `websockets` using the `websocket_rails`... is the thin server included in your gemfile?

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/socket.io"):

I get such issue when I receive post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out before, *websocket-rails isn't in active development* and it's last commit was a long time ago, as you can see reading [this question about alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247340/websockets-and-rails/31510229#31510229) and [this question about issues with websocket-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265047/websocket-rails-no-connections-in-production/31510427#31510427)

I would recommend you replace the websocket-rails with either a websocket framework that can work together with Rails, such as [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi), or use [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) which is a bit hardcore but very popular.